# How to resolve Apache Service path conflict - running both Apache and portable XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, mysql, services, xampp

I've got Apache 2.4.7 (Win32) running on Windows 7 and a visiting portable XAMPP on an external drive. After resolving the port issues I'm "only" down with having the "`Apache/MySQL Service detected with wrong path.. Found Path C:\... Expected Path E:\...`" errors as the service paths in registry are set to work with my local Apache/MySQL..

So far I've managed to use my external XAMPP with "less friction" by modifying the XAMPP start-and-stop bat-files for both Apache and MySQL to check upon failure the `ImagePath` values of the respective registry keys (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Apache2.4` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\services\MySQL`) and overwrite the `ImagePath` values when starting XAMPP and restoring the values when stopping.

But obviously this still leaves me using only one or the other at a time. Is there a way I could run them both simultaneously?

e.g. can I have 2 sets of Apache/MySQL services running or can this be tackled effectively some other way?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the way to go would be to uninstall apache service and run it as a console application for both instances: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#wincons

Same with MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-command-line.html

Since you can specify configuration options and files for both then you should be able to point them to use the correct instance.